# How to get a function to wait for the data to load from a second function before executing in angular

Tags: angular, async-await

I simply don't understand how async/await works; that's what I believe the problem is. I'm trying to load data from my service to my component, but I get an undefined. But the correct data loads properly from the function I'm calling. I imagine it's a way to re-structure the code so that async/await works, but I have no idea how.

Unfortunately, tutorials on async/await have just confused me more.

I've tried playing around with putting async/await in different places, but frankly I don't know what I'm doing.

This is the function in my component calling the other function from my UserService

```
async onSubmit() {
    console.log(await this.userservice.currentusercountry());
  }
```

This is the function in my userService

```
async currentusercountry() {
    let x;
    this.currentuser().subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value.country.toString());
      x = value.country.toString()
    });
    await console.log(x);
    return x;
  }
```

I expect to get something like this in my console.log

```
India         user.service.ts:65 
India         user.service.ts:68 
India         pg.component.ts:43
```

But instead I get

```
undefined     user.service.ts:68 
undefined     pg.component.ts:43 
India         user.service.ts:65
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this

```
async onSubmit() {

    let data = await this.userservice.currentusercountry();
    console.log(data);
    console.log('works!!!!!');
}
```

**userService**

```
async currentusercountry() {
  return promise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    let x;
    this.currentuser().subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value.country.toString());
      x = value.country.toString()
      resolve(x); // here we are passing value to our component
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: A simpler way to go from observable-based recipe to promise-based recipe is to use `toPromise()`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
async currentusercountry() {
    let x;
    this.currentuser().subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value.country.toString());
      x = value.country.toString();
  await console.log(x);
    return x;
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain in comments why your function works how it works.

```
async currentusercountry() {
    let x;  // declare some variable, its value is initially undefined
    this.currentuser().subscribe(value => { // everything inside subscription will 
      console.log(value.country.toString()); // be executed LATER
      x = value.country.toString()
    });
    await console.log(x); // this is executed instantly
    return x; // this is also executed instantly, with current value of x, i. e. undefined
  }
```

Here's how to fix it:

```
async currentusercountry() {
    const value = await this.currentuser().toPromise();
    const x = value.country.toString();
    console.log(x);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: I like how your code uses toPromise(); I'm assuming it makes "value" into an "object"? What exactly does toPromise() in combination with "await' do? 
Does it wait for the Promise to fulfill (and thereby become an object) before the next line of code is run?

Comment: First, `this.currentuser().toPromise()` is evaluated. The value of that expression is a promise. Then `this.currentuser().toPromise()` is `await`ed, like any regular promise, it's just syntacting sugar with `this.currentuser().toPromise().then(/* the entire rest of the function */)` underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use RXJS `switchMap`?

e.g:

```
onSumit(){
  this.userService.currentUserContry().subscribe();
}
```

**UserService**

```
currentUserContry(){
  return this.currentUser().pipe(
    switchMap((res) => {
      const x = value.country.toString()
      return of(x);
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be the things "more natural". You has two Observables

1. this.userservice.currentusercountry()
2. this.currentuser()

you can use forkjoin to has an unique subscription

```
forkjoin([this.userservice.currentusercountry(),this.currentuser()])
         .subscribe(res=>{
            console.log(res[0]) //the response from currentuserCountry
            console.log(res[1]) //the response from currentuser
          })
```